# Opción en g++ en Linux Suse 12 64bits para lanzar una advertencia al intentar sobredimensionar un array

Tags: c, linux

Quería saber si alguien conoce una opción para el `g++` de Linux Suse 12 64bits que dé error o "warning" cuando se intenta sobredimensionar un array.

Me explico con un sencillo ejemplo:

```c
int main (int argc, char *argv[])

{

  char vl_stcadena [5+1];

  char vl_stcadena_sal [10+1];

  strcpy (vl_stcadena, "");

  strcpy (vl_stcadena_sal,"");

  strcpy (vl_stcadena_sal, "1234567890");

  /* copiamos mas elementos vl_stcadena_sal (10) que para los definidos 
  vl_stcadena (5) */

  strcpy (vl_stcadena, vl_stcadena_sal);

  printf ("%s",vl_stcadena);


  return 0;

}
```

Las opciones de compilación son:

```bash
g++ -z muldefs -Wall -W -Wtype-limits -fPIC
```

El problema es que esto en Suse 12 64bits no da error `strcpy(vl_stcadena, vl_stcadena_sal)` y el `printf` de `vl_stcadena` funciona correctamente.

En la versión de Suse 11 de 32bits da un `core strcpy(vl_stcadena, vl_stcadena_sal)` al ejecutarlo y necesitaba que en Suse 12 64b también dé un `core` al ejecutarlo o al compilarlo de error o "warning".

Lo intenté con:

```bash
-Wtype-limits
```

pero no funciona.

Comment: No entiendo lo que estás preguntando. Dices que quieres un *warning* del compilador, luego dices que en otro hardware el código generaba un error del Sistema Operativo ... y que necesitas definir un comportamiento indefinido ... Estas mezclando conceptos como quien hace una ensalada ...

Comment: Sencillamente se trata de que se reproduzca el core que da en suse 11 32b al sobredimensionar un array . En suse 12 de 64b funciona no da corey necesito que en la compilación en suse 12 avise de este error o de core , es decir que suse 12 tenga el mismo comportamiento que en suse 11, que falle.

Comment: Lo que pides es imposible. Tal vez algún compilador te de un *warning* ... aunque lo dudo (¿ Que pasa si estás utilizando una librería externa y la función recibe un puntero ? ¿ Cómo sabría el compilador el tamaño de a lo que apuntas **antes** de ello ? ) Y el que el S.O. genere una excepción o no es dependiente de la plataforma. Es lo que tienen los *comportamientos indefinidos*, que es en realidad lo que tu estás generando con ese código.

Comment: Me lo imaginaba, si ... nada. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

No tengo constancia de que exista semejante opción no en g++ si no en ningún compilador; esto se debe a que `strcpy` recibe un puntero en crudo (`char *`) el cuál carece de información de tamaño y la propia especificación de la función indica que confía en el carácter de final de cadena para finalizar el proceso:

> `char *strcpy( char *restrict dest, const char *restrict src );`
>
> *Copies the null-terminated byte string pointed to by `src`, including the null terminator, to the character array whose first element is pointed to by `dest`*.
>
> *The behavior is undefined if the `dest` array is not large enough. The behavior is undefined if the strings overlap. The behavior is undefined if either `dest` is not a pointer to a character array or `src` is not a pointer to a null-terminated byte string*.

Traducción y resaltado míos:

> Copia la **secuencia de bytes terminada en nulo** que es apuntada por `src`, **incluyendo el terminador nulo**, a la formación de caracteres cuyo primer elemento es apuntado por `dest`.
>
> El comportamiento es indefinido si la formación `dest` no es suficientemente larga. El comportamiento es indefinido si las cadenas se superponen. **El comportamiento es indefinido si** `dest` no es un puntero a una formación de caracteres o **`src` no es un puntero a una cadena de bytes acabada en nulo**.

---

Si quieres tener mayor control y seguridad sobre la copia de cadenas, usa la versión segura de la función:

> `errno_t strcpy_s( char *restrict dest, rsize_t destsz, const char *restrict src );`
>
> *Copies the null-terminated byte string pointed to by `src`, including the null terminator, to the character array whose first element is pointed to by `dest`*.
>
> *The behavior is undefined if the `dest` array is not large enough. The behavior is undefined if the strings overlap. The behavior is undefined if either `dest` is not a pointer to a character array or `src` is not a pointer to a null-terminated byte string*.
>
> It may clobber the rest of the destination array with unspecified values and the following errors are detected at runtime and call the currently installed constraint handler function:
>
> - `src` or `dest` is a null pointer.
> - `destsz` is zero or greater than `RSIZE_MAX`.
>   `destsz` is less or equal `strnlen_s(src, destsz);` in other words, truncation would occur.
> - overlap would occur between the source and the destination strings.
>
> The behavior is undefined if the size of the character array pointed to by `dest <= strnlen_s(src, destsz) < destsz;` in other words, an erroneous value of `destsz` does not expose the impending buffer overflow.

Traducción mía.

> Copia la **secuencia de bytes terminada en nulo** que es apuntada por `src`, **incluyendo el terminador nulo**, a la formación de caracteres cuyo primer elemento es apuntado por `dest`.
>
> El comportamiento es indefinido si la formación `dest` no es suficientemente larga. El comportamiento es indefinido si las cadenas se superponen. **El comportamiento es indefinido si** `dest` no es un puntero a una formación de caracteres o **`src` no es un puntero a una cadena de bytes acabada en nulo**.
>
> Puede ensuciar el resto de la formación de destino con valores no especificados y los siguientes errores son detectados en tiempo de ejecución llamando a la función de error instalada en ese momento:
>
> - `src` o `dest` son punteros nulos.
> - `destsz` es cero o mayor que `RSIZE_MAX`.
>   `destsz` menor o igual a `strnlen_s(src, destsz);` en otras palabras, sucedería un truncamiento.
> - Las cadenas de origen y destino se superponen.
>
> El comportamiento es indefinido si el tamaño de la formación de caracteres apuntada por `dest <= strnlen_s(src, destsz) < destsz;` en otras palabras, un valor erróneo de `destsz` no informa sobre un desastroso desbordamiento de búfer.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario PaperBirdMaster.
Si, me he dejado la vista mirando las opciones del g++ y no veo nada que se ajuste a lo que busco.
Lo dicho gracias y un saludo.